# Calculating 2004 BL86 position using software

Tags: asteroids, software

Is it possible to view asteroid 2004 BL86 using Stellarium or the iOS Star Walk app?

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to describe the steps that I followed to show 2004 BL86 in Stellarium in my notebook:

- Open the *Configuration Window* by pressing F2
- Select the *Plugins* tab and from the left list select *Solar System Editor*
- Click in the *configure* button at the bottom
- Go to *Solar System* tab in the opened window
- Click the button *Import orbital elements in MPC format...*
- Click in the drop-down menu called *Select bookmark...* and select *MPCORB: near-Earth asteroids (NEAs)*
- Click the button *Get orbital elements*
- In the search field, type 2004 BL86 and select it once it appears below
- Click the last button called *Add object*
- Close the windows and then press F3 to open the *Search window*
- Start typing 2004 BL86 and once it is showed below, click in the magnifying glass to the right, that will get you to the position of 2004 BL86

Please let me know if that answers your question. I'm using Stellarium version 0.13.1... and sorry if my English is not very precise :)